# Edubuntu packages on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, system-installation

I found this [thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1666585)
with some over-explained but interesting things.

`the "linux-rt" pack doesn't exist in 10.10 this pack actually installs the realtime kernel but 10.10 doesn't have any. just try it without this part 
PS:i will make you a quick explanation of every part in this command line, because knowledge is power 
sudo - gives you a root privileges
aptitude - this is a text-based package manager similar to synaptic (you can successfully change this part with 'apt-get')
update - updates your software channels to current state 
&& - and (from C program language) 
install - install 
ubuntustudio-desktop - GUI of ubuntustudio system
ubuntustudio-audio - a collection of applications aimed at audio creation and editing
ubuntustudio-audio-plugins - A collection of LADSPA and DSSI plugins.
ubuntustudio-video - a collection of applications aimed at video creation and editing
ubuntustudio-graphics - collection of applications aimed at 2D/3D creation and editing.
linux-rt - a metapackge that installs you the latest complete Realtime Linux kernel available.`

I installed all the packages but didn't installed the Ubuntustudio-desktop because I wanted apps not new booting screen.

I want to install all apps of Edubuntu and don't want my Ubuntu to boot like Edubuntu i.e., I don't want edubuntu-desktop but all the packages of it. So instead of installing edubuntu-desktop what are the other name of packages?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following package bundle for your system according to your work-level!
`ubuntu-edu-preschool - Preschool (
ubuntu-edu-primary - Primary ( ages 6-12) educational application bundle
ubuntu-edu-secondary - Secondary ( ages 13-18) educational application bundle
ubuntu-edu-tertiary - Tertiary ( university level ) educational application bundle`

Comment: You are right. Changed my answer to reflect this procedure with the `14.04` version of Edubuntu